# How can I set the width of the image to imageView android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

How can I accomplish

Based on the image how can I set the image to imageview and in the background color is gray.

Here is the code I have tried

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAshLight"
        android:padding="11dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dunkincoffee"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But the result I am getting like:[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: not able to understand

Comment: I need to implement the design based on above screens

Comment: just the image part with grey bg right?

Comment: @Nehak yes Nehak.

Comment: added the solution in answer, hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
You need to set
`android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to ImageView

Updated your code as follow.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorAshLight"
            android:padding="11dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dunkincoffee"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried by adding the above code 
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dunkincoffee"
            />

Comment: but there is no equal spaces for background and the next image is not fitting the above requiremet

Comment: @Ali Ahmed I have updated the code and result images

Answer (score 0):

Use this class, this will adjust imageView's bounds with its image width automatically :

**1. Add this class in your project :**

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ManageHeightByWidthImageView extends ImageView {

    public ManageHeightByWidthImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ManageHeightByWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ManageHeightByWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {

            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();

            try {
                setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
            } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
            }
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

**2. Use this like following, for 1st image :**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAshLight"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <!--
                        Set the width value you want in place of "match_parent", for this linearLayout
        -->
        <com.example.myapplication.ManageHeightByWidthImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dunkincoffee" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**3. For 2nd Vertical Image :**

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAshLight"
            android:padding="10dp">
```

```
            <com.example.myapplication.ManageHeightByWidthImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/vertical_image" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

It will look like this :

[image]